# Twitter API and duplicate tweets

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using the twitter API via CodeBird PHP to display tweets using Ajax on a site. I'm having trouble preventing duplicates after the first call since `max_id` shows tweets after BUT INCLUDING the max_id.

Seems silly why they'd do it this way, to me, but I also can't seem to find anyone else asking the same question. I though this would be something that a lot of people come across. Which leads me to think I'm not doing something correctly.

```
    // Prepare Args
    $tw_args = array(
        'count' => 5,
        'trim_user' => true
    );

    // If we havea last id, set it
    if (isset($last_id)) {
        $tw_args['max_id'] = $last_id;
    }

    // new tweet arr
    $tweets = array();

    // get raw tweets
    $raw_tweets = (array) $cb->statuses_userTimeline($tw_args);

    // loop through tweets
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($raw_tweets); $i++) { 

        // Add just the ID and text to our new tweets array
        $tmp = array(
            'id' => $raw_tweets[$i]->id_str,
            'text' => $raw_tweets[$i]->text
        );

        array_push($tweets, $tmp);
    }


    // return tweets array
    return $tweets;
```

How do you prevent the twitter API returning the tweet with the same id as max_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well what you're trying to do, it seems that the `max_id` tweet is included in the `$raw_tweets` array?

If so, simply add a condition in your loop to not add the tweet with `max_id` as id to the `$tweets` array :

```
    // ...

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($raw_tweets); $i++) {

        // Check if the current tweet's id match max_id
        if($raw_tweets[$i]->id_str == max_id)
            continue;

        // Add just the ID and text to our new tweets array
        $tmp = array(
            'id' => $raw_tweets[$i]->id_str,
            'text' => $raw_tweets[$i]->text
        );

        array_push($tweets, $tmp);
    }

    // ...
```

Comment: That's what I've resorted to, but it seems that with each call I'm grabbing one more tweet than I need to, because I'm only going to remove it again. I thought there might be a better way...

Comment: According to [twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline), there is no way to not include the max_id tweet in the api response..

Answer (score 1):

If your platform is capable of working with 64-bit integers, simply subtract 1 from whatever value you have determined to be the max_id. According to the API documentation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines), "It does not matter if this adjusted max_id is a valid Tweet ID, or if it corresponds with a Tweet posted by a different user - the value is just used to decide which Tweets to filter." This will prevent receiving any duplicates.

However, if you cannot process 64-bit integers, the documentation says to skip this step, so I would assume there is no simpler workaround than the one offered by ZeusInTexas.